Arrow keys in FormKit taglist delete text instead of navigating within it
I am using a FormKit form with a FormKit taglist component and the :allow-new-values="true" option. Here's the issue I'm facing:
When the input field is empty and I start typing, I can use the arrow keys to navigate within the text (e.g., to correct a typo). However, if there's already a tag in the input and I type some text, the arrow keys (left/right) behave differently. Instead of allowing me to navigate within the typed text, they delete the text and shift the focus back to the existing tag.
Is there a way to keep the arrow key navigation functional within the typed text, even when tags are present? Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated.
I attempted to understand what controls this behavior but haven't been successful so far. I also tried using getNode to inspect the structure of the input field to identify potential causes, but I haven’t made any progress yet.

Please add enough code. Read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
